# Markup not being taken

Tags: discussion, formatting

In https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/31061/885 I see **anti-**gravity where the asterisks are not accepted as bold formatting because the closing one is not followed by whitespace.

In the preview shown while editing the answer, I saw that a U+FEFF character (zero-width no-break space) did the trick.  But when completing the edit, it went back to showing asterisks.

Normally I've run into the opposite problem, where unrelated asterisks get read as one spanning formatting directive.  But what do we do in this case, where it is not recognizing things as a formatting code?

Answer (score 3):

Could it be a case of

- **anti-**gravity `**anti-**gravity`

vs

- **anti**-gravity? `**anti**-gravity`

I think the problem is not that it should be followed by white space (th**i**s w**ork**s) but it cannot be preceeded by non-alphanum character (you see the **stars **).

Comment: Interesting to know.  But the rules used by the live preview are different!

Comment: For me (desktop), it works, though sometimes, it lags a bit before showing the correct version.

Comment: My edit showed the desired results in the preview, and was back to showing stars when I accepted.  Typing a space after the * and before the g, or a linebreak, "works" in preview even though it was still *pre*ceeded by a hyphen.

Comment: Ok, it is probably a confusion with the markup system. Well, at least the part where adding a space after the hyphen changed the outcome. The rules of that system aren't perfect. For the Live-view, however, I don't know. But it sounds like a bug, and [Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) is probably the best place to report it.

Comment: Yes, for the preview, the best place to report it is probably Meta Stack Exchange, not Meta Worldbuilding. (And no matter where you report it, make sure you tag it `bug` and not `discussion`.) It's known that there are some minor differences between the preview and the final result, but that doesn't mean reporting those as bugs is not worthwhile.

Comment: I came here first because different SE's have different options and details of what is allowed in markup.  They may be interacting in a distinct way.